# Get active attributes of productid in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to grab the all the attribute active for a productid but I always get ALL the attributes. This is my code :

```
    $product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
    $attribute= $product->getResource()->getAttribute("color"); 
    $optionscolor = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach ($optionscolor as $option) {    
         echo "<option value='".  $option['value']."'>".  $option['label']."</option>";  
    }
```

For this product, I have 4 colors (Black, Red, Blue and Yellow). But this code give me all the 12 colors... Why ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the frontend model, not the source model of this attribute.

Try this:

```
$optionscolor = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```